# Amsrefs and arxiv

Tags: bibliographies, arxiv

I have a problem concerning arXiv ID in References. I saw that there are numerous question on that and it seems to me that BibTeX is not a good solution, so I tried to us amsrefs for this. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\cite{carlsson2014equivariant}
\bibliography{MojaBibliografia}
```

and the relevant bib entry:

```
@misc{carlsson2014equivariant,
      title={Equivariant motivic homotopy theory}, 
      author={Gunnar Carlsson and Roy Joshua},
      year={2014},
      eprint={1404.1597},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={math.AT}
}
```

This code still does not print the arXiv ID. How can I go around this? Alternatively, I can use biblatex - but I am not sure which style would be good for mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BibTeX with `amsrefs` only to get a preliminary `.bbl` file that should be included in the document (with modifications).

Here I add a new `arXiv` type.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineSimpleKey{bib}{primaryclass}{}
\DefineSimpleKey{bib}{archiveprefix}{}

\BibSpec{arXiv}{%
  +{}{\PrintAuthors}{author}
  +{,}{ \textit}{title}
  +{}{ \parenthesize}{date}
  +{,}{ arXiv }{eprint}
  +{,}{ primary class }{primaryclass}
}

\begin{document}

\cite{carlsson2014equivariant}

\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{carlsson2014equivariant}{arXiv}{
  author={Carlsson, Gunnar},
  author={Joshua, Roy},
  title={Equivariant motivic homotopy theory},
  date={2014},
  eprint={1404.1597},
  archiveprefix={arXiv},
  primaryclass={math.AT},
}

\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks! Just one more question - if I wanted to put primary class in square brackets, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can create a command analogous to \parenthesize, say
\newcommand*{\bracketize}[1]{[#1]}
and replace +{,}{ primary class }{primaryclass} by +{}{ \bracketize}{primaryclass}.